# What is the difference between Targeted LDP and Directed LDP in MPLS?

Tags: mpls, ldp

Please explain the main differences (use cases) between Targeted LDP and Directed LDP in MPLS ?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Directed LDP* is not a term that appears in the LDP specification ([RFC 5036](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5036#section-3.5.2).)

Perhaps you're trying to understand the difference between *Basic Discovery* which uses *LDP Link Hellos* and *Extended Discovery* which uses *Targeted Hellos.*  Targeted LDP is for exchanging messages with a distant, non-adjacent peer.

Targeted LDP can allow routers to use LDP-signaled LSPs to reach next-hops connected to each-other by sending traffic through the data-plane with an additional, *inner label* which is signaled using tLDP.  In today's networks, BGP, with its different scaling properties, has taken over much of the role for which tLDP can be used.